# Error with setCompressionType

Tags: java, image, compression, jpeg, jai

Is there someone that can help to correct this code?

I'm working with `JAI` and I'm trying to compress JPG file to Losse-less
here's my code

```
     `ImageWriter writer= (JPEGImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
     javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam param = (JPEGImageWriteParam)                  
     writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
     param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
     param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LOSSLESS");`
```

It's always error in this part  `param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LOSSLESS");` 
the error is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type!
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam.setCompressionType(ImageWriteParam.java:1023)`

Answer (score 0):

You can only use compression types that are supported. Check which are supported by [`param.getCompressionTypes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#getCompressionTypes%28%29).

Other then that, try this code (using newer jpeg lossless standard `JPEG-LS`):

```
ImageWriter writer = 
    (ImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param= writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(param.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");
```

Comment: oh there's a problem with your code `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Updated answer (using `JPEG-LS`).